# VueJS / Electron : How to get "child_process" working?

Tags: vue.js, electron, child-process

In my VueJS / Electron app, I need to call an exe file (working under windows environment).

In my project, I made this js file:

```js
import exec from "child_process";

export default {
  opt() {
    exec("tool.exe", function(err, data) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(data.toString());
    });
  }
};
```

However, when I launch the app with "npm run electron:serve" I got this error into the debug tool of Electron :

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: child_process__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function"
```

I don't know where I'm wrong...

Any ideas ? Thanks ;)

Comment: I think you are not importing it right. It should be: `import { exec } from "child_process"`

Comment: Changed from exec to { exec }, same error message :/

Comment: Still not working... 

A quick console.log on exec give me an undefined...

Any ideas ? Really don't know why it's not working :/

Comment: Apparently `child_process` doesn't work in the browser. Did you make any more progress on this? I have the exact same error.